# Custom program error code 0x0 while sending a transaction

Tags: web3.js, transactions, rent, sendtransactionerror

While trying to create a transaction containing as instructions the creation of a mint account, initialize mint instruction and ATA creation), it gives me the custom program error code 0x0 while trying to perform the transaction, which I found to be something like: "Lamport balance below rent-exempt threshold".

So, basically, the following would be the transaction creation:
[image]

Followed by airdropping some SOL to all keys (just in case):
[image]

Right after that, the transaction is sent:
[image]

Then, the custom error code 0x0 at instruction 0 appears.
There no intermediate lines of code between the snippets

What am I missing here? Any suggestions?

EDIT: After some research, it looks like the error might be due to the account that I’m trying to create in instruction 0 being already in use. I will confirm this and update here

EDIT2: It looks like since it is a System Program error, the code 0x0 relates to the account being already in use, however it gives me always the same error despite using Keypair.generate for both baseaccount and mintKey

[image]

Kind of stuck in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.
Basically, the airdrop to the mintKey, before sending the transaction, was causing it.
As soon as the airdrop was removed, it worked perfectly.